# How to pass ID list to stored procedure using Hibernate in Grails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I am trying to pass an ID list as a parameter to MySQL stored procedure in Grails. I found a workaround that does work but the problem is that it is too slow since it uses FIND_IN_SET MySQL function that iterates through an id list passed in as a string ("1,2,3,4").

Procedure call:

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def rawQueryResult = sql.rows("call testProcedure(?)", ["1,2,3,4"])
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testProcedure`(
    IN idList TEXT,
)
BEGIN
    SELECT tt.id

    FROM test_table tt
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tt.id, idList);
END
```

This does work however when I have a large ID set, the procedure execution lasts for a long time. Is there a better way to pass ID list to procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> This does work however when I have a large ID set, the procedure
> execution lasts for a long time. Is there a better way to pass ID list
> to procedure.

No.  There aren't other ways to pass the ID list into a stored procedure that would be better in terms of how long the execution of the stored procedure takes.